# Xpath, find node between two other nodes

Tags: xpath

I need to construct a generic XPath to find the correct node, where the criteria are date and time. e.g. to find the node for "03 May", "12:17:44"

The XML has has a date and time tag.
Inconveniently, the date tag is populated only for the first occurrence of the day. (The time tag is always populated)

I have tried this:

```
/itemisationTable/row[@Date="03 May"]/following-sibling::row[@Time="12:17:44"]
```

it works fine, but it is not correct, because this

```
/itemisationTable/row[@Date="03 May"]/following-sibling::row[@Time="21:12:06"]
```

also finds a result, which it should not.

---

My other problem is that

```
/itemisationTable/row[@Date="03 May"]/following-sibling::row[@Time="09:34:13"]
```

should find a node but it does not.

---

I would be greatful if someone could help me with the XPath for this, as it exceeds my Xpath skills.

Here is a snippet of the XML

```
<itemisationTable index="1" name="Belgium - SMS/Data" total="1.522">
<row Date="03 May" Time="09:34:13" Number="xphone.com" Description="Roaming Data" Origin="Belgium" Destination="Other Provider" InBundle="" Taxable="T" Duration="12.57 MB" Cost_exc_VAT="1.258" />
<row Date="" Time="10:43:41" Number="4428" Description="xphone SMS" Origin="Belgium" Destination="UK" InBundle="B" Taxable="" Duration="1" Cost_exc_VAT="0.000" />
<row Date="" Time="10:43:44" Number="4428" Description="xphone SMS" Origin="Belgium" Destination="UK" InBundle="B" Taxable="" Duration="1" Cost_exc_VAT="0.000" />
<row Date="" Time="12:17:44" Number="4408" Description="xphone SMS" Origin="Belgium" Destination="UK" InBundle="B" Taxable="" Duration="1" Cost_exc_VAT="0.000" />
<row Date="" Time="21:10:50" Number="4412" Description="xphone SMS" Origin="Belgium" Destination="UK" InBundle="B" Taxable="" Duration="1" Cost_exc_VAT="0.000" />
<row Date="" Time="21:11:55" Number="4412" Description="xphone SMS" Origin="Belgium" Destination="UK" InBundle="B" Taxable="" Duration="1" Cost_exc_VAT="0.000" />
<row Date="04 May" Time="21:12:06" Number="4412" Description="xphone SMS" Origin="Belgium" Destination="UK" InBundle="B" Taxable="" Duration="1" Cost_exc_VAT="0.000" />
<row Date="" Time="21:22:34" Number="4412" Description="xphone SMS" Origin="Belgium" Destination="UK" InBundle="B" Taxable="" Duration="1" Cost_exc_VAT="0.000" />
<row Date="" Time="21:23:23" Number="4412" Description="xphone SMS" Origin="Belgium" Destination="UK" InBundle="B" Taxable="" Duration="1" Cost_exc_VAT="0.000" />
<row Date="" Time="21:23:31" Number="4412" Description="xphone SMS" Origin="Belgium" Destination="UK" InBundle="B" Taxable="" Duration="1" Cost_exc_VAT="0.000" />
<row Date="05 May" Time="21:23:56" Number="4412" Description="xphone SMS" Origin="Belgium" Destination="UK" InBundle="B" Taxable="" Duration="1" Cost_exc_VAT="0.000" />
<row Date="" Time="21:30:45" Number="4412" Description="xphone SMS" Origin="Belgium" Destination="UK" InBundle="B" Taxable="" Duration="1" Cost_exc_VAT="0.000" />
<row Date="" Time="22:24:35" Number="4431" Description="xphone SMS" Origin="Belgium" Destination="UK" InBundle="B" Taxable="" Duration="1" Cost_exc_VAT="0.000" />
<row Date="" Time="22:24:38" Number="4431" Description="xphone SMS" Origin="Belgium" Destination="UK" InBundle="B" Taxable="" Duration="1" Cost_exc_VAT="0.000" />
<row Date="06 May" Time="" Number="xphone.com" Description="Roaming Data" Origin="Belgium" Destination="Other Provider" InBundle="" Taxable="T" Duration="2.59 MB" Cost_exc_VAT="0.264" />
<row Date="" Time="07:09:15" Number="4483" Description="xphone SMS" Origin="Belgium" Destination="UK" InBundle="B" Taxable="" Duration="1" Cost_exc_VAT="0.000" />
</itemisationTable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky! This isn't particularly efficient, but it *is* a working solution (with XPath 2.0):

```
/itemisationTable
  /row[@Date=$date]
  /(self::row | following-sibling::row[
    not(./preceding-sibling::row[@Date != ""][1]/@Date != $date)
  ][not(./@Date != "" and ./@Date != $date)])[@Time=$time]
```

With XPath 1.0, this gets hairier:

```
/itemisationTable
  /row[@Date=$date]
  /following-sibling::row[
    not(./preceding-sibling::row[@Date != ""][1]/@Date != $date)
  ][not(./@Date != "" and ./@Date != $date)][@Time=$time]
| /itemisationTable/row[@Date=$date][not(./@Date != "" and ./@Date !=$date][@Time=$time]
```

Set `$date` and `$time` through your XPath engine -- in XMLStarlet, for instance, this would be `--var date='"03 May"'`; evaluating XPath in an XQuery engine it would be with `declare variable $date="03 May"`; etc.

The important thing is to use `preceding-sibling` to backtrack and look at whether you've crossed a boundary, ruling out any nodes for which that's true.

For a language with enough expressive power to build an efficient solution, I'd want to switch to XQuery.

---

To allow copy/paste testing, the below has been successfully used at http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html:

```
/itemisationTable   /row[@Date="03 May"]   /following-sibling::row[     not(./preceding-sibling::row[@Date != ""][1]/@Date != "03 May")   ][not(./@Date != "" and ./@Date != "03 May")][@Time="21:11:55"] | /itemisationTable/row[@Date="03 May"][not(./@Date != "" and ./@Date != "03 May")][@Time="21:11:55"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. I'm not actually using an engine, just preparing the Xpaths for another system and testing them using http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

I tried this in the tester, 

  /itemisationTable
  /row[@Date="03 May"]
  /(. | following-sibling::row[
    not(./preceding-sibling::row[@Date != ""][1]/@Date != "03 May")
  ][not(./@Date != "" and ./@Date != "03 May")])[@Time="12:17:44"]

but it says it cannot compile.
I can't see what is wrong. Maybe you can

Comment: Updated with a query compatible with XPath 1.0 (which is ancient -- 3.0 is current -- but also what a number of implementations, most notably libxml, use).

Comment: Thank you again. I have tried your new Xpath 1.0 in freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html'
as            
/itemisationTable
  /row[@Date="03 May"]
  /following-sibling::row[
    not(./preceding-sibling::row[@Date != ""][1]/@Date != "03 May")
  ][not(./@Date != "" and ./@Date != "03 May")][@Time="12:17:44"]
| /itemisationTable/row[@Date="03 May"][not(./@Date != "" and ./@Date !="03 May"][@Time="12:17:44"] 

It's still refusing to compile. So either your query is too complex for it, or something else is wrong

Comment: @AndrewSittermann, if you want to test with xmlstarlet -- the libxml client I used myself here -- the command was as such: `xmlstarlet sel -t -m "$(<test.xpath)" -c . -n <test.xml`

Comment: @AndrewSittermann, ...however, the expression I gave works for me in the tester you linked as well.

Comment: Sorry to be a bit dense here ... I can't get the freeformater tester to accept it. would you mind pasting Xpath without variables which you got it to accept?

Comment: @AndrewSittermann, if it's refusing to compile, does that mean it's giving an error message? Can you give that message here? It's possible that different browsers' XPath implementations are giving different results, so also tell what browser you used.

Comment: Unable to compile '/itemisationTable /row[@Date="03 May"] /following-sibling::row[ not(./preceding-sibling::row[@Date != ""][1]/@Date != "03 May") ][not(./@Date != "" and ./@Date != "03 May")][@Time="12:17:44"] | /itemisationTable/row[@Date="03 May"][not(./@Date != "" and ./@Date !="03 May"][@Time="12:17:44"]/'. Using Chrome

Comment: @AndrewSittermann, sorry 'bout the lag -- been busy. Updated with a copy-and-paste-ready string.

Comment: @AndrewSittermann, ...btw, where did the trailing `/` come from? I don't have that in either of my queries.

Comment: ...and, on testing, that trailing `/` appears to be the cause of the error.

Comment: Super. It is of course now working for me too. Thanks for the copy-pastable query, Charles.
(p.s. I really don't know why I could not get it to work myself even without the trailing / which I added to see if it would help)